# Looking for an iPhone app or script that turns off “Cellular Data” when on 2G and then BACK ON when on 3G

Tags: iphone, applications, cellular-data

As some of you might know, 2G (GSM) or 2.5G (GSM/Edge) does not support data and calls at the same time. Using the Internet while on 2.5G and lower causes incoming calls be bounced.

3G does support data and calls at the same time by pausing Data while a call is received.

I am an architect, working in and around buildings under construction.

I usually get a low (2G) signal when I enter one and a good (3G) signal when I come out. Together with all the apps I have, the phone finds itself using my Internet connection when on GSM, causing calls to be dropped. I'm effectively unreachable.

I don't want to use 2G internet, only 3G. I would like cellular data to be on only when on 3G. My phone calls take priority over Internet connectivity when on 2G.

Comment: My iPhone on 3G is able to do voice and data simultaneously. How do you mean it pauses the data?

Comment: @RandolphWest He said it doesn't work simultaneously only on GPRS and Edge, which AFAIK is correct.

Comment: The sentence "3G does support data and calls at the same time by pausing Data while a call is received." is what I'm referring to.

Comment: On a hardware level it does not interrupt internet but you can test it... while you are on a call... it stalls... but does not disconnect.

Comment: Great use case. The answer for most people that need voice but travel around is to simply disable cellular data. Knowing you're actively using the data - turn data on. Once you get done, make sure you tell it off before you leave the 3G area. It's a real pain in the butt, but as you see the jailbreaking tools are a bit of a mess.

Comment: My parents kept complaining I didn't answer my phone on the bus, now I know why as I'm on the internet on the bus. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution... BUT IT DOES NOT WORK ON THE IPHONE 4S.

---

All of the areas I drive through are covered by 3G (metro Houston area), and there is no reason that my phone could not stay in 3G. After some determination & google searching I have finally found a solution. (Note that I tried the “Edge” button in SBSettings, however it simply turns off ALL data, including 3G. My solution: edit the phone’s files to stop it from ever going to Edge!

What is required for the edit:

- A jailbroken iPhone
- SSH client (such as putty)
- OpenSSH installed on your iPhone (found in Cydia)
- Basic knowledge of command prompt/SSH use

What you will need to do:

- SSH to your phone logging in as “root” (password is usually alpine).
- Navigate to /var/wireless/Library/Preferences/
- Edit the file csidata (I use nano as my editor)
- Find the line that reads “GsmRegistrationModel::fRatSelection=0×1″ & change it to GsmRegistrationModel::fRatSelection=0×2 (For those that need to know, 0×1 = 3G & Edge Data, 0×0 is Edge only, and 0×2 is 3G only)
- Save the file & reboot your phone!

### Your iPhone 4 will now ONLY use the 3G network. Note, this will NOT allow you to use your data service if you are in an Edge only area (yes, they do still exist). I should also note that the entire process will need to be redone if you accidentally use SBSettings to turn your data settings on or off.

Found here 
http://planet-iphones.com/2011/04/01/iphone-4-3g-lock-disable-edge/

Answer (score 1):

A left field suggestion:

Turn off cellular data and use a Mifi device (such as the Huawei E585) for your internet connection.
Yes this does mean another device and another SIM card, but you may be OK with that.

I've used this combination with an iPhone and it works really well.
You can leave the Mifi in your pocket, so forget it's even there
(just remember to charge it!).
You get other benefits, for example it means using a laptop or tablet "in the field" is possible also as they'll be net-connected.

Answer (score 0):

There are no scripts for the iPhone by default and apps can't really change settings like that for you. Your only option is to jailbreak and look around Cydia for something. I would suggest look for an app or tweak that does profiles but when I was jailbroken I couldn't find anything like that.